# Is this code okay design-wise?

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.x

I needed some OR filtering in my class method, but I feel really bad about this piece of code. Is this how it should be? Or can I design it somewhat better?

```
class FooBar:
  @classmethod
  def get_current_objects(cls, role='passenger',
                          add_params=None, offset=0, limit=10):
     """
     The logic behind this is to return cls.objects with filters
     defined in params var, but I stumbled accross
     the need to use OR in the query, whilst keeping some `add_params`
     in `params` var.
     """
     params = {}
     # ... here are some 'params', lots of code I need to keep, skipped ...
     if add_params:
        # this piece below feels awkward
        for k, v in add_params.copy().iteritems():
            if (v == True) and (role == 'passenger'):
                add_args.append(Q(**{k: True}) | Q(**{k: False}))
                del add_params[k]
            elif (v == False) and (role == 'driver'):
                add_args.append(Q(**{k: True}) | Q(**{k: False}))
                del add_params[k]
            elif (type(v) == str) and (role == 'passenger'):
                add_args.append(Q(**{k: v}) | Q(**{k: u''}))
                del add_params[k]
            elif (type(v) == str) and (role == 'driver'):
                add_args.append(Q(**{k: v}) | Q(**{k: u''}))
                del add_params[k]
        params.update(add_params)
    # -----------------------------
    return cls.objects.filter(*add_args, **params)[offset:offset + limit]
```

How do I not repeat myself in this circumstances?

Comment: Where you right `if (v == true)`, you can use `if (v)`, same for `if (v == false)` --> `if (!v)`
Since you do the same lines 2x 2x, i'd suggest useing `and` and `or` statements to create if big `if` statement written over multiple lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure about the syntax, but this is how I would write it.

```
 if add_params:
    # this piece below feels awkward
    for k, v in add_params.copy().iteritems():
        if ((v == true) and (role == 'passenger'))          # edited the true/false in
        or ((v == false) and (role == 'driver')):
            add_args.append(Q(**{k: True}) | Q(**{k: False}))
            del add_params[k]

        elif (type(v) == str)                    # (x or y) and (x or z) -> x and (y or z)
        and ((role == 'passenger') or (role == 'driver')):
            add_args.append(Q(**{k: v}) | Q(**{k: u''}))
            del add_params[k]

    params.update(add_params)
# -----------------------------
return cls.objects.filter(*add_args, **params)[offset:offset + limit]
```

Comment: Thanks, seems pretty. Only thing I can't use if (v), because it produces True if v is non-empty string, I need boolean indeed.

Comment: @nikkey2x2 `if v is True` and `if v is False` -- always use `is` when you actually need to compare to boolean literals.

Comment: And btw, `((type(v) == str) and (role == 'passenger')) or ((type(v) == str) and (role == 'driver'))` can be just `(type(v) == str) and ((role='driver') or (role='passenger'))`.